# Wildfly on Docker: Deployment directory scan failed due to inaccessible deployment directory

Tags: linux, docker, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy Wildfly 20 in Docker but I'm getting this error message and the EAR file is not deployed:

```
2021-09-01 12:06:03,368 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) 
WFLYDS0043: Deployment directory scan failed due to inaccessible deployment directory: 
/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:20.0.1.Final
RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin ManagementRealm
ADD ./standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
```

And I map the deployments directory to a Docker volume with Docker compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  wildfly:
    image: image-wildfly:latest
    container_name: cont_wildfly
    networks:
      - net1
    command: /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 -b 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9990:9990"
    volumes:
      - vol_wildfly:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments
networks:
   net1:
     name: net1
     
volumes:
  vol_wildfly:
     name: vol_wildfly
```

If I log into the container, I can see the EAR file in the deployments directory. I even created a doDeploy file manually, and nothing happens. What is the issue?

**Note:** if I upload the EAR file from the administrator console, it works, so the problem is with the volume.

**UPDATE**

This is the directory ownership when the volume is mounted, mapping to `deployments` directory in the container:

```
/ # ls -ld vol
drwxrwxr-x    2 1000     root          4096 Sep  5 11:22 vol
```

Comment: What are the ownership and perms on your mounted volume? In the default image, the directory belongs to `jboss(1000):root(0)` and has mod '0775` (and `0664` for  contained files).

Comment: See update, does this mean that user jboss does not have access to the directory owned by root?

Comment: What commands you ran to get that warning message ? Can you share `standalone.xml` ?

Comment: @Philippe this is the [standalone](http://sofiana.com/standalone.xml) file. I start the process with `docker-compose up -d` Wildfly starts automatically in the image

Comment: How did you build your docker container ?

Comment: The image I built with `docker build --tag=image-wildfly .` , the container is built when the docker compose starts based on the yaml.

Comment: I ran these two commands without any issues : `docker build --tag=image-wildfly .;docker-compose up -d wildfly`    Can you remove your container/images and start fresh ?

Comment: did you also map a volume to contain the deployments directory? I removed the images and the containers many times

Comment: Yes, I kept everything as is, including standalone.xml.

Comment: and when you copied from your operating system to the volume an EAR file it deployed?

Comment: I cannot see any EAR file in what you posted.

Comment: the deployment happens when you drop a file (EAR, WAR or JAR) in the deployments folder, WildFly scans the directory, expands it and also creates a file with name 'ear.deployed' That's the problem

Comment: can you run `docker-compose down` to delete any objects corresponding to the compose file? if so do that and then add the file again to the new volume after running `docker-compose up` (no `-d` option to see logs while in action)

Comment: Noam, I deleted everything including the volume, and starting compose without the -d option worked, Wildfly detects the EAR file and deploys it. Something was wrong with the volume? It's the first time I delete it.

Comment: If I understood correctly and you've ran `docker-compose down` to delete everything, so yes, it seems the issue was with the volume as I suspected, its one of the few things that didn't change and that worked nonetheless for Philippe (meaning using a fresh volume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, it seems that the permissions for the file and the volume didn't match or the volume had an unrelated error causing wildfly to fail while scanning for deployments.

After running `docker-compose down` to clean any stale docker object that persisted between tests and changes the process ran as expected and maybe even successfully.

If this accumulation of events is confirmed by @ps0604 I see this as sealed